# Paraview PVpython running subscript from master script - relative path

Tags: python, paraview, pvpython

I've got master script for PVPython which runs about 3-5 subscripts. Apart from aguments I always have to specify the subscript path in order to run it like this:

```
'/home/username/Documents/MainFolder/Subscripts/subscript1.py'
```

Is there a way to get this path automatically as the master script would be for example in same main folder like this:

```
'/home/username/Documents/MainFolder/Masters/master1.py'
```

When I run a relative path reference from PVPython [like here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-script-file-path/) I get an error, so maybe there's another way to do in PVPython?

Thanks for the tips

*edit*

The problem is that with

```
import sys
print(sys.path[0])
```

I get printed

```
/usr/lib/python38.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you point to (https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-script-file-path/), there is a section `Get the absolute path of the running file`.

Use

```py
os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

to get the absolute path of your master script. Then you can recreate the absolute paths of your subscripts from relative ones (see the `os` doc : https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)